# IIS Manager - can not connect using certain user accounts

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am having some trouble with what should be a very simple task.

I have set up IIS 8 on server 2012

If I log in using a domain admin account, or the first admin account that was created when the machine was setup, I can connect to IIS Manager no problem

If I try and connect using a user that I have since created locally on the machine, and added to the local admins group. I can not connect.

Now, here is the extra wierd bit:
If I remote in using the new admin account, and try and connect to IIS using the domain or other admin accounts that previously worked (if I remote in using those) i get the same error and I cant connect!

Steps I am using:

1. Remote in using the NEW admin account
2. Launch IIS (IIS doesnt show local server)
3. Connect to server (localhost)
4. Type in credentials (ANY account)

the error is:
"Could not connect to the specified computer"
"Details: Unable to connect to the remote server"

HELP!
&
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found out that it require to run IIS Manager with administrator permissions. Try to run IIS Manager as Administrator and it should solve the problem. Or try to access the manager console from Computer Management (mmc), which must be run with Administrator privileges.